# Is it bad practice to define constants using class static methods?

Tags: c++, constants

Instead of using #define or const, I usually define constants using class static methods as follows:

```
//AppConstants.h
#include <string>
class AppConstants{
public:
    static int getMax();
    static std::string getPrefix();
};

//AppConstants.cpp
#include "AppConstants.h"
int AppConstants::getMax(){
    return 30;
}

std::string AppConstants::getPrefix(){
    return "myprefix";
}
```

I do this usually when creating a mobile app, which I would like to save the compile time when each time change the value for testing. Is it a bad practice?

Comment: that makes no sense. how exactly do you save compile time?

Comment: @BЈовић: When changing one of those constants, you only need to re-compile one file, instead of having to re-compile all files that reference one of the constants.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau depends where you put the constant. If it is in the source file, then you do not need to recompile.

Comment: I don't know that what you are doing is bad practice, per-se.  But I think calling them "constants" is bad practice.  Specifically, getMax cannot be used as a case in a switch statement or to specify the size of an array.  Therefore, getMax is not a "constant".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, and it's unnecessary too. You can declare constants in headers and define them in source files just like functions:

```
class AppConstants {
public:
  static const int Max;
  static const std::string Prefix;
};

const int AppConstants::Max = 30;
const std::string AppConstants::Prefix = "myprefix";
```

Especially in the case of the string, this has the advantage of not constructing a new one every time you access it.

It also has the disadvantage of being affected by C++'s unspecified global initialization order, so be careful if you use the constants from the initialization of other global variables/constants.

Comment: While I mostly agree on this, why do you think it is a problem constructing a string every time?

Comment: It's an unnecessary heap allocation if the string is too long for SBO.

Comment: it should allocate only if you modify the string - not otherwise

Comment: Converting a string literal to a std::string allocates unless the std::string employs the Small Buffer Optimization and the string is short enough to fit. Copy-on-Write strings are not allowed in C++11, and CoW only applies to std::string's copy constructor anyway, not the one that takes a character pointer.

Comment: could use [operator""s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) to avoid extra allocations

Comment: @Caleth `operator""s` is a convenient syntactical shortcut, but it doesn't magically get rid of the allocations. If you really want to avoid allocations, you have to use `const std::string& getPrefix() { const static std::string prefix = "myprefix"; return prefix; }`